# When I run sfdx after installing Salesforce CLI in my new Mac, no error and no output

Tags: salesforcedx, mac-os-x

I have installed the Salesforce CLI version 6.44 in my new Mac. The installation runs smoothly with no errors. Then I run the command 'sfdx --help' in the terminal window. It gives neither any error nor any output.

Have probably missed something?

Comment: don't think that's a valid command, try sfdx --version

Comment: I agree. That is not a valid command. It's same when I run 'sfdx --version', nothing happens. Is there a way to see something is going wrong?

Comment: this link should help - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_log_messages.htm

Comment: If you go in to a terminal, what's the output of `which sfdx`?

Comment: it gives me `/usr/local/bin/sfdx`

Comment: should I install the package with `sudo` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get some logs by looking into USER_HOME_DIR/.sfdx/sfdx.log .

If you are on macOS then simply cd into the home directory using cd $HOME and then cd again to the .sfdx folder .

You will find sfdx.log file if you open the .sfdx folder .This should have more info for you .

If you are behind the firewall , then update your environment variables as per the below instructions

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Comment: Somehow this started working now. I believe it is related to some setup done by Infra guys when provisioning my new MacBook. I have to setup the HTTP_PROXY to use SFDX CLI behind corporate firewall.

Comment: @wawass Added some more info so that helps others as well

Answer (score 0):

When installing Salesforce CLI with npm, you install the sfdx and sf executables separately using the commands below:

sfdx executable: `npm install sfdx-cli --global`

sf executable: `npm install @salesforce/cli --global`

If you miss installing the second executable your CLI won't be complete and it won't show anything.